# Using temporary variable when creating a Netezza VIEW

Tags: sql, netezza

Here's a simple view I'd like to create, but I'd like only FOUR columns in the final view: a, b, c, e.  I would like to define d for temporary use in determining the value of e, but then I do not want d to be part of the resulting view.

```
create view v as
select a, b, c, a+b+c as d, 
case when d > 1000 then 1
     when d > 100 then 2
     when d > 10 then 3
     else 4 END as e
from tbl;
```

Is there any way in Netezza SQL to define such a temporary value?

In this simple example, certainly I could replace each of my "when d" statements with "when a+b+c" every time, but my real-world scenario is more complex than illustrated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
create view v as
    select a, b, c,  
           (case when d > 1000 then 1
                 when d > 100 then 2
                 when d > 10 then 3
                 else 4 
            end) as e
        from (select tbl.*, (a + b + c) as d
              from tbl
             ) t;
```

Comment: Your solution looks very promising! (btw... I think you meant to leave off the "d" on the first "select", as that's the value I don't want left in the view, but I knew what you meant.)  Thanks for the tip!!!